# every keypress pops up shudown prompt on new laptop!

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, asus, amd-processor

I've just installed ubuntu 21.04 on a new rog strix laptop (ryzen 5800h, rtx 3060 gpu), I get prompted with a shutdown prompt after every keypress - after cancelling the prompt, the keypress is processed properly.

This is rather tedious!

Any ideas where to start to fix this.

Install was straightforward after turning off bitlocker and disabling secure boot in Windows

** I've just checked, this problem happens even booting from memory stick - I thought it had been OK, but I'd just never used the keyboard...

Comment: If I let it go to sleep, then I can type the password to unlock normally, then I'm back in prompt hell

Comment: Have you installed Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I've tried 20.04 now, but although it boots OK from the usb stick, it totally fails to boot once installed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a workaround, but in settings - power, set power behavior to nothing and the prompt goes away.

however as keys don't autorepeat, I suspect all is not quite right in the keyboard department.

Also plugging in an external keyboard fixes it, and auto repeat works, so I think the built in keyboard has a different interface that needs a driver change.